# Nodal Analysis of an Inverting Operational Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I am trying to derive the closed-loop gain of a basic Inverting Op-Amp circuit using nodal analysis and the model that includes its non-ideal parameters. The equation I derived is incorrect, and it's most likely due to the initial KVL equation.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Analysis]

Comment: You need two equations the one for *V1* node  $$\frac{V_1 - V_S}{R_S} + \frac{V_1}{R_{IN}} + \frac{V_1 - V_O}{R_F} = 0 $$ and for *Vo* node $$\frac{V_O - V1}{R_F} + \frac{V_O - A(0 - V_1)}{R_O}= 0 $$

Comment: You are right! You have to derive an equation for "V1" first, then the equation for the closed-loop gain.